# Script ends abruptly with a Terminated message

Tags: bash, scripting, kill

This is my bash script. All it does is to check whether a service has started and whether some processes are running as expected.

It ends abruptly with a "Terminated" message. I tried debugging it with the `set -x` flag, and I still don't know what is going wrong. Stack Overflow and Google don't show me any other people with a similar problem.

The script has permissions of 755. Some commands are obfuscated, for obvious reasons.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x 

DAEMON_BIN=/etc/init.d/init-god
DAEMON_BIN_START="${DAEMON_BIN} start"
DAEMON_BIN_STOP="${DAEMON_BIN} stop"
SOME_VARIABLE="foo"

CHEF_CONFIG_FILE_PATH="/path/to/file"
NODE_INFO_FILE="/mnt/node_info/properties"

function get_key_value (){
    value=$(grep -Po "(?<=^${1}:).*" ${NODE_INFO_FILE})
    echo $value;
}

eval $DAEMON_BIN_STOP

nohup pkill DAEMON &> /dev/null

nohup pkill -f resque &> /dev/null

eval $DAEMON_BIN_START

sleep 15

PROCESS_COUNT=`ps aux | awk '/[p]rocess-name/' | wc -l`

NODE_NAME=`get_key_value node_name`

if [[ $NODE_NAME -eq $SOME_VARIABLE  && $PROCESS_COUNT -eq 1 ]]; then 
    echo "DAEMON and scheduler are running fine." ;
else
    echo "A problem with DAEMON has occured." ;
fi

EXPECTED_PROCESS_COUNT=`get_key_value no_of_workers`
ACTUAL_WORKER_COUNT=`ps ax | grep [r]esque-[0-9]`

if [[ $EXPECTED_PROCESS_COUNT -eq $ACTUAL_WORKER_COUNT ]]; then 
    echo "Correct Number of workers initialized." ;
else
    echo "More workers exist than are permitted." ;
fi

for (( i=0; i<${EXPECTED_PROCESS_COUNT}; i++ )); do
    WORKER_NAME=`get_key_value worker_${i}`
    COUNT=`ps ax | grep ${WORKER_NAME} | grep -v grep | wc -l`
    if [[ $COUNT -eq 1 ]]; then
        #statements
        echo "${WORKER_NAME} is running."
    else
        echo "${WORKER_NAME} may not be running or might have more than 1 copies."
    fi
done
```

The debug output of the script is as follows:

```
+ DAEMON_BIN=/etc/init.d/init-god
+ DAEMON_BIN_START='/etc/init.d/init-god start'
+ DAEMON_BIN_STOP='/etc/init.d/init-god stop'
+ SOME_VARIABLE=foo
+ CHEF_CONFIG_FILE_PATH=/path/to/file
+ NODE_INFO_FILE=/mnt/node_info/properties
+ eval /etc/init.d/init-god stop
++ /etc/init.d/init-god stop
.
Stopped all watches
Stopped god
+ nohup pkill DAEMON
+ nohup pkill -f resque
Terminated
```

Why does this script exit with a "Terminated" message? What should I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I provided an answer to the question, but I also want to note that the script is broken by design. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

Comment: Thank you. I am taking a look at it, especially the process killing part.

Comment: Please provide the name of the script when you are using ps :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you are calling `pkill -f resque` it is also matching your script, sending it a SIGTERM. If you are unable to add additional restrictions on the `pkill` commands such as more exact matching, you will need to kill PIDs one at a time to ensure the script is not killing itself. Here is an example:

```
pids=( $(pgrep -f resque) )
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
  if [[ $pid != $$ ]]; then
    kill "$pid"
  fi
done
```

Comment: mypid=$$; pids=($(pgrep -f resque|grep -v $mypid))